# Is there any way to use both Borland Compiler and graphics.h in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi, borland-c

I am currently trying to use both Borland Compiler in CodeBlocks as I do not find Turbo C and its environment suitable for coding. Now I realize that graphics.h library is not working in CodeBlocks while using Borland Compiler. I know there is a way while using MinGW compiler, but I need to write other programs in Borland Compiler.

Comment: You can use it in Code::Blocks if you install an old enough version of mingw. You likely need a compiler from about 15 years ago for this old / unsupported software to work. I am talking about this [https://winbgim.codecutter.org/](https://winbgim.codecutter.org/) download that uses gcc-3.4.5. A modern gcc version like 10.2 will be incompatible with such old binaries.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to use the Borland compiler?

Comment: Turbo C and Turbo C++ (both IDE and compiler) were obsolete about 25 years ago and don't even support the first C++ standard (C++98). Run away from that old garbage as fast as you can.

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- Turbo C and C++ are by no means garbage. They were cutting edge at the time. I agree that there's no reason to use such **old** software. But being old does not mean being garbage. :-) (I worked for Borland during that time...)

Comment: If you are looking for a good graphics libraby, use the SfML library in C++. It is a simple procedure to configure it into codeblocks

Comment: @PeteBecker OK. I may have used too strong words there. I apologize. I agree, they were good in their day and I used them back then. I probably should have said " run away from that obsolete and non-standard implementation"..

Comment: @PeteBecker One thing I loved about those tools back then was how easy it was to see the CPU register values while debugging your program.

Comment: This repository may help make this old code work with a more modern version of mingw: [https://github.com/Duthomhas/WinBGIm-fixed-sort-of-](https://github.com/Duthomhas/WinBGIm-fixed-sort-of-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with CodeBlocks, the advice is to install the latest version (20.03).
However, CodeBlocks has long been able to use the Borland bcc32 compiler (version 5.5 or 5.6, it seems to me) by setting the toolchain paths appropriately. 
While using the Borland compiler from CodeBlocks, this does not allow you to use the VCL library only available via the Borland C++ Builder IDE.